# Error C2059: syntax error 'constant'

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code in a header file:

```
enum {false,true};
```

and I have my  main function in main.c. if I change the extention to main.cpp
I get the following error:

```
Error C2059: syntax error 'constant'
```

Im using visual c++, any Idea why`?

Comment: You've found one of the reasons why C++ cannot be made 100% backwards compatible with C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`true` and `false` are keywords representing constant values in C++. You cannot use them to name things such as enum values.

As an example, the following would compile

```
enum { false_, true_ };

int main() {}
```

Comment: It is also true for other constants (enumeration for instance) that are already defined elsewhere (I encountered a problem when I have defined an enumeration value named NO_ERROR which is already defined defined in winerror.h).

Answer (score 1):

`false` and `true` are reserve words in C++. You can't redefine it as variable.