# need solution to: Error C2059: syntax error 'constant'

Tags: c++

I yesterday asked the following question: [Error C2059: syntax error 'constant' [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614221/error-c2059-syntax-error-constant)

The code is:

```
enum {false,true};
typedef char bool;
```

I now know why I get the error but I have no solution to my problem. 
Any idea will be appreciate.

Comment: If you're coding in C++ you already have `bool`, `true` and `false`. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Im trying to compile the code in c++ compiler, and then build a dll

Comment: It's invalid C++ code, so you can't compile it with a C++ compiler. Why are you trying to compile these 2 lines with a C++ compiler ?

Comment: @RezaAyadipanah: Well, you can't: it's not possible to use keywords as names. If you want to use a boolean type, just delete these and use the builtin `bool`, `true` and `false` keywords. If you want your own not-quite-boolean type for some weird reason, use different names.

Comment: Then you'll have to modify those two line, or use the preprocessor to remove them from your build (`#ifdef __cplusplus...`)

Comment: You are asking for a solution, but you have not described the problem clearly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error C2059: syntax error 'constant'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614221/error-c2059-syntax-error-constant)

Answer (score 2):

Simply delete those two lines. Any code that uses `bool`, `true` or `false` will still compile, since these are keywords in C++.

The only problem could be if some evil code relies on this `bool` type being able to store other values. However, such code is almost certainly wrong anyway.

Comment: I get the following Error:     error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl nameOnly(char const *)"

Comment: @RezaAyadipanah: That's an unrelated problem. Most likely, either the definition of that function is missing, or the file that contains it is not being linked into your build. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816) might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same code for both C++ and C projects, then you have to conditionally remove those declarations depending on compiler. This can be done with the preprocessor like this:

```
#if !defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(__bool_true_false_are_defined)
enum {false,true};
typedef char bool;
#endif
```

When compiling with a C++ compiler, the preprocessor macro `__cplusplus` will be defined, but it will never be defined in a C compiler. The preprocessor macro `__bool_true_false_are_defined` is defined if you include `<stdbool.h>` which also defines the boolean types and values.

In fact, I suggest you don't do your own declarations at all, but if you're not compiling with a C++ compiler, then simply include `<stdbool.h>` instead.

Comment: Although it's a bad idea in C as well, since it will clash with `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Correct, added check for that too.

Comment: I get the following Error: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl nameOnly(char const *)"

Comment: @RezaAyadipanah That's completely unrelated to this problem, and should be its own question. But as a free tip, you might want to check that all source/object/library files you need are indeed in your project.